# Android: Close activity from PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, activity-finish, preferencefragment

my application is running just in background.
As activity I have just Settings and, after pressing Start button, a service is called and activity is finished.
In order to this I'm using MainActivity who call PreferenceFragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainSettingsFragment()).commit();
}
```

In order to start Service or exit from activity I've created a menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 
    case R.id.action_exit:
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.action_start:
        Intent intentService = new Intent(MainSettingsActivity.this, ReminderService.class);
        startService(intentService);
        finish();
        break;
    return true;
}
```

This is my very simple PreferenceFragment, used to show settings_layout

```
public class MainSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_layout);
     }
}
```

In settings_layout is also defined two Preference item: Start and Exit.

I would like to move functions Start and Exit placed in menu, as item in layout.
It's easy to create an intent in xml file letting start the service, but I don't know how to close the activity.
How can I implement finish() function inside of Activity (who call PreferenceFragment) in order to kill her self?
How can I get the event "Press Exit" inside of Activity?
Getting the event inside PreferenceFragment is enough to implement a listener, like:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPref, String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    /* Do something */
    } 
}
```

but after that I have no idea how to close the activity.
Any Idea?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF I get this correct you would like to close the activity from a fragment?
Why don't you use getActivity() in your fragment and then call finish()?

Comment: Yes, that's great! My question was easy but I wanted to be clear describing scenario, but also answer was pretty easy, I really didn't think about `getAcivity`. Thank you so much!